# Ruby: Checking if Nested Array Contains Array

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble checking if a nested array contains a single array. For example:

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
a.each do |i|
  b= i.inspect
  puts a.include?(b)
end
```

The output it false and false. If anyone could help out that would be great.

Comment: Do you want to look for a specific array or just any array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
a.each do |i|
  # puts i.to_s
  puts a.include?(i)
end
```

This should do it. `inspect` is not necessary. This outputs true and true. Uncomment the comment in the code to see the output.

Answer (score 0):

1. Flatten the array, [Array.flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten)
2. Find the target element, [`include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-include-3F)